# выпадающее по :hover меню отображается не корректно при замене <button> на <a>

Tags: hover, выпадающий-список

грубо говоря, экспериментирую в этом примере
https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.php

если заменить кнопку на ссылку, выпадающее меню отображается не под родительской ссылкой, а выше.
скажите плиз куда рыть.

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решён. добавлен отступ сверху, и выпадающее меню спозиционировано как надо.
одно не понятно: почему на  отсчет ведется снизу как будто он relative по-умолчанию, а на , даже если ссылка внутри дива и position: relative, отсчет ведется сверху, и нужно сдвигать вниз